# spatialite NodeJS module seems too slow

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, spatialite

I'm developing an electron app that uses spatialite.

I did a simple test on a spatialite table with about 52000 polygons. (can't tell how many vertices...)

Running the following query in spatialite_gui takes about 0.5 seconds.
Running the same query through electron app takes about 3 seconds.

SQL: SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE ST_Intersects(Geometry, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(x y)', 4326));

Yes there is an spatial index on spatialite.

Does spatialit_gui loads the full database into memory? Maybe that's why is much faster.
Any ideas about how to improve performance on electron app? Thanks.

Comment: I'm planning to make an electron app which will use spatialite also and was curious about your journey. Is your project open-source? Is there any resource you recommend?